# undefined control sequence error with footnote

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to add a footnote in my latex document but I have an undefined control sequence error. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

% general incantations
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb} %for \degree C symbol
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[everyline=true,framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{mparhack}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
% For diamond and club and space
%\usepackage{fdsymbol}
%Automated appendices
\usepackage[titletoc,title,header]{appendix} %advanced functionality
%language settings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[australian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%page setup
%this where we adjust the binding offset, if relevant
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage} % for page 1 of n footers
%cross referencing
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%maths stuff
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%lists
\usepackage{enumitem}

%working collaboratively
\usepackage[backgroundcolor=yellow]{todonotes}

% bibliography file using harvard
%\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,citestyle=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib} % with extension

%glossary for acronyms
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,toc,section=subsection,numberedsection=nolabel]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries

%line spacing
\linespread{1.25}

%$\heartsuit\varheart\diamondsuit\vardiamond\clubsuit\spadesuit$
\begin{document}

\footnote{text}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection Examples}
I am a subsection

\subsubsection{Sub Subsection Example}
I am a sub subsection



\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think there is a problem with $\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}$ but I need this package as I am using a template, though I don't know what it does exactly

Comment: "minimal"?????? in a minimal example you would not be able to remove any `\usepacakge` line and still show the problem.

Comment: the error is from `\usepackage{dblfnote}` but I have no idea if you really use that package or why you have `\footnote` not connected to any text,

Comment: It is a bad idea to include any package in the preamble that you do not know you are using. Certainly you should not load etex, you shouldn't specify inputenc twice (with recent latex you don't need to specify at at all)

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle, it solved my problem to remove dblfnote package. As I mentioned I couldn't remove more dependencies as it was a template that I am using. Each time I removed a package, I had an issue somewhere, different from the above. So for me it is a minimal example, otherwise I have to give all the code. Would you mind adding an answer so that I close this one?

Comment: No it is not a minimal example. You could (and should) have worked down your example, deleting packages not needed in the example, and checking the problem existed. Then the example would have been much smaller in fact you would not have needed to ask the question as you would have seen the error go. Remember you are asking people to trace tex's behaviour to find the source of the error and it is **much** harder to do that if you load 56 packages. There is no such thing as a "template" in latex. Always start with an empty preamble and just add packages as you need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is an incompatibility with

```
 \usepackage{dblfnote}
```

But as you are not using that package you can simply delete it.

Several other `\usepackage` lines  should also be deleted eg `etex` should never be used, you load `inputenc` and `graphicx` twice for example.